# How to COUNT objects with a date in the past in ms SQL query

Tags: sql, date, count

I would like to count all objects that have a date in the past.
My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE endDate WHEN (endDate < getDate()) then 1 else null end)
FROM employeeHasFunction
```

The format of the date is build in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE employeeHasFunction (
[..]
    startDate DATE NOT NULL,
    endDate DATE NOT NULL,
[..]
);
```

If it could be done in a where clause thats also possible.

Thanks

Comment: `startDate` or `endDate` in the past, one of them or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query should work, but the more typical method is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM employeeHasFunction
WHERE endDate < getDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` instead of `count()` :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (endDate < getDate()) then 1 else 0 end)
FROM employeeHasFunction;
```

Comment: @dnoeth. . . I think original query has some typical errors.

Comment: @dnoeth. . . There is one redundant `CASE endDate WHEN (endDate < getDate())` ?